# Characters in PS1 variable

Tags: bash, ps1

My PS1 variable :

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

I understand everything except the first part `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]`. What is the purpose of this part? It doesn't seem to affect my prompt. In fact my question could be reduce even more to this part : `\e]0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape ]0 (the `\e]0` you're interested in) modifies an XTerm title bar.  More at this link:  http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/xterm-title-bar-manipulations.html

Everything inside the `[]`:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]
```

Is marked as a non-printing character, so `bash` can do the right thing with line wrapping, etc.  In this case that means "put the current user@hostname and current working directory in the title bar".  The `\a` is a bell character.

Comment: The link doesn't talk about Escape 0. There is only info for Escape 1 and 2. Why is there a bell character at the end?

Comment: Yes it does, it's right there in the example.  When the bell character is there is a question for the person who wrote that prompt string in the first place.  Maybe he likes beeps.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that link myself.  The bell character is ascii 7 which is the "end editing title bar" character in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the escape sequence to [color your prompt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#Slightly_fancier_prompts).